# Why do I have the error of "Undefined variable: req"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I want to display a map of the search. But I keep getting "undefined variable: req" notification. What should I change from my following code:

```
var jQuery_1_8_2 = jQuery.noConflict();
    $(function () {
        var array = JSON.parse('{!! !empty($total_search_query) ? json_encode($total_search_query) : "[]" !!}');
        console.log(array);
        $('#map2').vectorMap({
            map: 'indonesia-adm1_merc',
            backgroundColor: '#ADF3F0',
            regionStyle: {
                initial: {
                    fill: '#FFFFFF'
                },
                hover: {
                    fill: '#175083'
                }
            },
            zoomButtons: false,
            zoomOnScroll: false,
            zoomOnClick: false,
            zoomMax: 1,
            normalizeFunction: 'polynomial',
            onRegionClick: function (event, code) {
                var url = '{{ route("search", ["q" => $req->input("q"), "province" => ":id"]) }}';
                url = url.replace("%3Aid", code.toLowerCase());
                window.location.href = url;
            },
            onRegionTipShow: function (event, label, code) {
                var map = $('#map2').vectorMap('get', 'mapObject');
                var regionName = map.getRegionName(code);
                var a = array.find(a => a.name === myTrim(regionName))['count'];
                
                label.html('<div class="map-tooltip"><h4 class="header">' + regionName + '</h4><p class="description">Total: ' + a + '</p></div>');
            }
        });
    }(jQuery_1_8_2));
```

Comment: You need to change `$req->input("q")` to `request()->get("q")` where you are generating url from route in `onRegionClick` function

Comment: Share with us the controller plz.

Comment: @UrjaSatodiya thank you. it works! still in the same code. Why is the URL I'm getting always show "&amp%3B"? I just need "&" in the URL. How do I change the URL? sample: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/cari?q=query&amp%3Bprovince=13&page=1", I want to change it into "http://127.0.0.1:8000/cari?q=query&province=13&page=1"

Comment: @niasanny What does this line do `url = url.replace("%3Aid", code.toLowerCase());` in same function?

Comment: @UrjaSatodiya without this code `url = url.replace("%3Aid", code.toLowerCase());` I got `http://127.0.0.1:8000/cari?q=query&amp%3Bprovince=%3Aid&page=1`. so, I put this code to replace **%3Aid**

Comment: @niasanny you can use `{!! !!}`  blade syntax to prevent encoding of the url

Comment: @UrjaSatodiya how do i write it down?

Comment: @niasanny write `var url = '{!! route("search", ["q" => $req->input("q"), "province" => ":id"]) !!}';` and comment out `url = url.replace("%3Aid", code.toLowerCase());` line

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the `$req->input("q")` part that you can determine via looking at the error message which complains about `$req` not being defined. The reason is that in your Laravel code at some place you have stored the result of `request()` into a variable called `$req`, which does not exist in this context. This is the view part, while you have probably parsed the result of `request()` in your controller. As a result you will need

```
request()->input("q")
```

instead.